# Opening Microsoft Edge in Elevated mode (use case: open via Selenium)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, microsoft-edge, elevated-privileges

I am trying to open Ms Edge in Elevated Mode, but I am unable to do so. (Windows 11)

I have tried to open it manually too, but the Elevated option is always set to 'No'.

Image showing Edge Elevated Mode Status:

[image: Image showing Edge Elevated Mode Status]

I have tried using the below options via selenium

```
    admin_edge_options = webdriver.IeOptions()    
    admin_edge_options.use_chromium = True
    admin_edge_options.add_argument('--ie-mode-test')
    admin_edge_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    admin_edge_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    admin_edge_options.add_argument('--disable-software-rasterizer')
    admin_edge_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    admin_edge_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    driver = webdriver.Ie(options=admin_edge_options)
```

Manually I have tried

1. Run as Administrator:

- Right-click on the Microsoft Edge shortcut or executable.
- Choose "Run as administrator" to launch Edge with elevated privileges.

2. Run after Temporarily disabling windows defender

I tried to perform the same on another Machine (windows 10),facing the same issue.

My config.
python 3.12
selenium 4.18.1

Edit 1:
Added edge://version screenshot.
[image: edge://version screenshot]

Comment: Unclear how this is related to python but... it's not a programming question, and is off-topic here. Maybe ask on [su]?

Comment: Is there any error message after you click "Run as Administrator"? Can you run other apps with elevated privileges on that machine? Could you please open *edge://version/* page in Edge and provide the screenshot of this page?

Comment: @DavidMakogon Hi, Thanks for your reply. 
I want to open the it via selenium (web-automation framework) which can be used with Java/Python/Javascript/Ruby/C#.

My use case is to open with Selenium, I am using python, but I don't mind if anyone can share a working solution for it in any other language. (I just mentioned the config. as additional details if needed)

I mentioned the manual approach too because I am not sure if its the code which is not working if there are some restriction which don't allow me to open it in  elevated Mode. 

I will check Super User too, Thanks !

Comment: Hi @YuZhou, Thanks for your reply!
I can open command prompt, Ms Word with elevated privileges, but when I do the same with browsers (Chrome/Edge) the elevated status remains 'No'.  My use case is Edge.
I have added the screenshot for edge://version in my edit above, hopefully it helps. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test and search information and found that it's by design. For chromium-based browsers, it's not recommended to launch the browser Elevated for any reason, as it leads to potential security issues. For these reasons it has built in the behavior to automatically "de-elevate" the browser if it is launched as an administrator.

If you still want to open Edge with elevated privileges, you can try opening it with an administrator account and add `--no-sandbox` flag to Edge. For example, logging in Windows with an administrator account and use the code below to open Edge in Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
 
admin_edge_options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
admin_edge_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
 
driver = webdriver.Edge(options=admin_edge_options)
 
driver.get('https://bing.com')
 
time.sleep(25)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks @YuZhou,  I am logged in as admin and I have already tried the argument, but when I check the Elevated status it displays 'No'. Do I have to update any other setting on my machine for it to work ? 
`For these reasons it has built in the behavior to automatically "de-elevate" the browser if it is launched as an administrator.`  I was not aware of this, thanks for pointing it out. Appreciate your help !

Comment: Please make sure kill all Edge instance in Task Manager first. Except that seems no other setting need to be updated. For manually test, you can add `--no-sandbox` in Edge shortcut properties like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLwOo.png. Then double click the shortcut to open Edge and check the Elevated status.

Comment: If that still doesn't work, I suggest that you give up opening Edge/Chrome as administrator. Actually, it's not recommended and not supported to do so.

Comment: I understand its not recommended, however for my use case its required, which is why I am trying to achieve it, thanks ! 
I have tried your suggestions, with a little tweak I am to run in Admin mode. Thanks Again!!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by messing around settings.

1. Open Edge file location.
2. Open properties -> compatibility. Click change settings for all users
3. Check  'Run this program as an Administrator'.
4. Apply. Ok

Now, if we open Edge it opens with Elevated Status 'Yes'.

If its still opening with Status 'No' . As highlighted by @YuZhou

1. Open Task Manager
2. Go to Details
3. End all Microsoft Edge instances.
4. Open Edge

Works in Selenium via existing code, no changes.